# change AlertDialog fonts in titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using [titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) to create android mobile application
How can i change font family and other properties for AlertDialog box?
i need to change it to arabic language  font
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There is no font property for the [AlertDialog object](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog-object), but you could simply construct your own transparent window with a custom view, buttons, and fonts to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: While this answer is accurate, does anybody not see the problem with this? I mean... you can't customize an alert box at all? You can give a view for the message area in android and you can slightly customize it in iOS, but you can't do something simple like... center the title?!? Change the font?!? The suggestion is "recreate the wheel." That's kind of silly.

Comment: @vbullinger it is what it is. Since Titanium is open source, change it and make a pull request if it's that much of an issue for you. Just a thought.